# How can I resolve 500.19 on all my application?

Tags: iis, .net-core

I create **.Net Core web application**, I have to download **.NET Core Runtime & Hosting Bundle** but when I do that all my application get this error.

[image: error]

Even if I uninstall it, I still have the error.
When I try to run it in the command prompt with **dotnet** command it works but it doesn't work on **IIS 10**.

**UPDATE :**

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ProjectName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You probably need to reveal all contents of that web.config file for others to review. Or you use Jexus Manager to analyze, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: The 500.19 means there is something wrong with your web.config file. As lex li said please share your web.config file to get more idea about the issue. you need to ensure the application works just fine in your development environment. You could also prefer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle) how to host asp.net core site in iis.

Comment: Check the full error message on the server since 500 error is generic issue. You can also read this blog https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal the problem is if I only have an issue with my web.config all the other application in IIS will work, but acutally all my application doesn't work.

Comment: @LexLi I update my post